# Firebase - How to update many children and not delete others in AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I want to use update() on firebase ref to update many children in one operation.
To do this I passed the object with values to change.

Here is the output of console.log(angular.toJson(change,1))

```
{
  "10": {
    "otherRubies": 30
  },
  "11": {
    "otherRubies": 30
  }
}
```

At the beginning i have:

[image]
Then i do:

```
var refUsers = new Firebase(FBURL).child('users/');
refUsers.update(change);
```

So i want to have:

[image]

but instead of that i get:

[image]

Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: did you try update operation

Comment: Yes, sorry i pasted wrong version... no is ok but still does'n work

Comment: I'm not sure how angular or angularFire are involved in your example?

Comment: i think workaround is to include old values with new values

Answer (score 5):

Update is not a recursive operation. So it's calling set on the child paths. If you call update at users/, you're saying don't delete any keys under user/ which are not in my data, when you want to say, don't delete any keys in the child records of user/.

Instead, iterate the records and call update on each:

```
var refUsers = new Firebase(FBURL).child('users/');
for(key in change) { 
   if( change.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
      refUsers.child(key).update( change[key] );
   }
}
```

Comment: no, this must be done in one operation. Transaction will be good ideal for now.

Answer (score 0):

With Firebase 3 you can do the update by writing :

```
update = {};
update['10/otherRubies'] = 30;
update['11/otherRubies'] = 30;
refUsers.update(change);
```

This way of updating the data is not in the documentation but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample of recursive update:

```
function updateRecursively(path, value) {
  for (let key in value) {
    if (value[key] instanceof Object) {
      updateRecursively(`${path}/${key}`, value[key]);
    } else {
      firebase.database().ref(`${path}/${key}`).set(value[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
updateRecursively('users', {
  "10": {
    "otherRubies": 30
  },
  "11": {
    "otherRubies": 30
  }
})
```